# Add parameter to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the HAML template (entities\index.html.haml) which have:

**form_tag**

```
= form_tag intities_path, :method => :get do   
 Include: 
 - @all_numbers.each do |number|
    = check_box_tag "numbers[#{number}]", "yes", @checked_numbers.has_key?(number)   
= submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

As you see if the user press "Refresh" button all checked checkboxes *will be passed to controller automatically as hash*.

But I need to have on my page **two additional hyperlink**.  Something like this:

```
%a(href="/entities/?quality=better") Make better
%a(href="/entities/?quality=best") Make best
```

I am using them to pass to controller one additional parameter - quality.

There are two problems with them:

- If I click the hyperlink, my code will not pass numbers-parameter to controller.
- If I click the Refresh button, my code will not pass current quality-parameter to controller.

How can I modify my code so when I click the hyperlink or button the controller gets all params: quality and numbers?

Or I can ask my question **on the other way**:  I have the page with some set of parameters.  How can I change one of the parameters and refresh the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself: [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) to pass data on submit form and link_to to pass parameters on the link click.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add a button (tried this with submit) and set the "name" attribute to something like "quality" and set the value parameter. Make two of those buttons with different values, and in HTTP only the cliked one will be passed as quality.